# How to write BOM marker to a file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have some working code with a crutch to add BOM marker to a new file.

```
  #writing
  File.open name, 'w', 0644 do |file|
    file.write "\uFEFF"
    file.write @data
  end

  #reading
  File.open name, 'r:bom|utf-8' do |file|
    file.read
  end
```

Is there any way to automatically add the marker without writing cryptic `"\uFEFF"` before the data? Something like `File.open name, 'w:bom'  # this mode has no effect` maybe?

Comment: Please do not use a BOM for UTF-8!!! It is ***neither required nor recommended*** by the Unicode Consortium.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, master. I came for the problem with a different approach and patched my template engine to respect Encoding.default_external.

Comment: "No, a BOM can be used as a signature no matter how the Unicode text is transformed: UTF-16, UTF-8, or UTF-32." http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html

Comment: unless you are in windows world and they make you apply a BOM to ascii files to be recognized as UTF-8

Comment: @tchrist actually the BOM is recommended by the Unicode Consortium in some circumstances. See http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom10

The circumstances are: 1. conforming to certain protocols (e.g. Microsoft .txt files); 2. to specify encoding or endianness of text streams where that would otherwise be unclear, within protocols that allow it.

Comment: Without this BOM, Microsoft Excel would not recognize the UTF-8  .csv, but expecting  cp1252 encoding, which is not capable for many characters like  Ş and the conversion from utf-8 to cp1252 with `encode` will lead to "Undefined conversion Error"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas I think your manual approach is the way to go, at least I don't know a better way:

http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/miscellaneous_m17n_details

To quote from JEG2's article:

> Ruby 1.9 won't automatically add a BOM to your data, so you're going
>   to need to take care of that if you want one. Luckily, it's not too
>   tough. The basic idea is just to print the bytes needed at the
>   beginning of a file.

Comment: You do not want a BOM in a UTF-8 file!!

Comment: Can you please explain why we don't want to do that? :) @tchrist

Comment: @fab  because it's unnecessary with utf8.  With utf16 the bom indicates whether the file is big endian or little endian, there is a bom for one and a bom for the other and the bom is mandatory, but with utf8 there aren't two variant boms, the bom is unnecessary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom?rq=1

Answer (score 11):

**** This answer lead to a new gem: [file_with_bom](http://rubygems.org/gems/file_with_bom) ****

I had the similar problem in the past and I extended `File.open` with additional encoding variants for the `w`-mode:

```
class File
  BOM_LIST_hex = {
      Encoding::UTF_8      => "\xEF\xBB\xBF", #"\uEFBBBF"
      Encoding::UTF_16BE => "\xFE\xFF", #"\uFEFF",
      Encoding::UTF_16LE => "\xFF\xFE",
      Encoding::UTF_32BE => "\x00\x00\xFE\xFF",
      Encoding::UTF_32LE => "\xFE\xFF\x00\x00",
    }
  BOM_LIST_hex.freeze
  def utf_bom_hex(encoding = external_encoding)
    BOM_LIST_hex[encoding]
  end

class << self
  alias :open_old :open
  def open(filename, mode_string = 'r', options = {}, &block)
    #check for bom-flag in mode_string
    options[:bom] = true if mode_string.sub!(/-bom/i,'')

    f = open_old(filename, mode_string, options)
    if options[:bom]
      case mode_string
        #r|bom already standard since 1.9.2
        when /\Ar/   #read mode -> remove BOM
          #remove BOM
          bom = f.read(f.utf_bom_hex.bytesize) 
          #check, if it was really a bom
          if bom != f.utf_bom_hex.force_encoding(bom.encoding)
            f.rewind  #return to position 0 if BOM was no BOM
          end
        when /\Aw/  #write mode -> attach BOM
          f = open_old(filename, mode_string, options)
          f << f.utf_bom_hex.force_encoding(f.external_encoding)
        end #mode_string
    end

    if block_given?
      yield f 
      f.close
    end
  end
  end
end #File
```

Testcode:

```
EXAMPLE_TEXT = 'some content öäü'
File.open("file_utf16le.txt", "w:utf-16le|bom"){|f| f << EXAMPLE_TEXT }
File.open("file_utf16le.txt", "r:utf-16le|bom:utf-8"){|f| p f.read }
File.open("file_utf16le.txt", "r:utf-16le:utf-8",  :bom => true ){|f| p f.read }
File.open("file_utf16le.txt", "r:utf-16le:utf-8"){|f| p f.read }

File.open("file_utf8.txt", "w:utf-8", :bom => true ){|f| f << EXAMPLE_TEXT }
File.open("file_utf8.txt", "r:utf-8", :bom => true ){|f| p f.read }
File.open("file_utf8.txt", "r:utf-8|bom",              ){|f| p f.read }
File.open("file_utf8.txt", "r:utf-8",                     ){|f| p f.read }
```

Some remarks:

- The code is from pre 1.9-times (but it still works).
- I used `-bom` as a bom indicator (ruby 1.9 uses `|bom`.

Some needed fixes to be better:

- use `|bom` instead `-bom`
- use the standard `r|bom` for reading
- make it ruby 1.8 and 1.9 enabled

Perhaps  I will find some time tomorrow to refactor my code and provide it as a gem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for my project that would be overkill.

Comment: +1 for the gem. I guess you could contact the Ruby or Rubinius guys and made it merged into official distribution.

Comment: @AleksanderPohl The gem is published http://rubygems.org/gems/file_with_bom I hope I made no oversight.

Answer (score 1):

a trimmed version from @knut

```
File.open("file_utf8.txt", "w:utf-8") do |f|
    f << "\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8")
    f << EXAMPLE_TEXT 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# read content form old file
original_content = File.read(file_path)
# define UTF-8 BOM
bom = "\xEF\xBB\xBF"
# new file，add BOM in the head of content
File.open(new_file_path, "w:UTF-8") do |file|
  file.write(bom + original_content)
end
```