# How to get past Excel CSV encoding nightmare: "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8" using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, parsing

I'm trying to parse CSV files in Rails, which works great except for anything saved in Excel (testing with Version 16.26) for both Windows and Mac (CSVs saved in Numbers & Google sheets work fine). Any character with an accent produces `"Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xEF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8".`

Excel claims it saves in UTF-8.

I want accented characters to not throw errors when I upload CSVs saved in Excel.

Things I've tried:

1. setting the read encoding to bom|utf-8 (as per the [BOM link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543225/how-to-avoid-tripping-over-utf-8-bom-when-reading-files)), utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, windows-1252, ascii-8bit (and cycling through each of these in an array incase one fails then dropping it out of the array)
2. current code uses ISO8859-1:UTF-8 which is supposed to read in ISO8859-1 then encode in UTF-8
3. Creating a tempfile, converting it to binmode, CSV.parse(temp.path,  encoding: "bom|utf-8") per [the first answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756008/file-encoding-issue-when-downloading-file-from-aws-s3).

```
data = CSV.parse(csv, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, skip_blanks: true, encoding: 'ISO8859-1:UTF-8')
```

It also works if I take a csv saved in Excel, then save it in google sheets or Numbers then upload it. Unfortunately, Excel is the most common CSV uploaded by our users.

Comment: This should be the [Byte Order Mark (BOM) problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543225/how-to-avoid-tripping-over-utf-8-bom-when-reading-files). Worst case scenario, just strip off the first two bytes and read it in using `parse`.

Comment: @tadman: 3 bytes, assuming a utf-8 bom

Comment: I've tried setting the read encoding to bom | utf-8 and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using [csvreader gem](https://github.com/csvreader/csvreader). The built in CSV parser sucks in rails.