# rails - UTF-8 character encoding not working in csv files on excel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

RUBY_VERSION = ruby-1.8.7-p358
RAILS_VERSION = rails (2.3.2)

code snippet

````
```
def export_to_excel
    csv_text = get_csv_string
    headers['Content-Type'] = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    headers['Cache-Control'] = ''
    send_data csv_text, :type => 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', :disposition => "attachment;filename = "new_report.csv"
end
```
````

**Problem** : When I download the file and open it in Excel or Libre office it shows junk characters. I have to manually go and set the encoding as UTF-8 for the characters in file to be recognised.

**Thing I've tried out**

1. [Character encoding issue exporting rails data to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639153/character-encoding-issue-exporting-rails-data-to-csv/19678391)
2. changing the csv string using Iconv to WINDOWS-1252 using Iconv.iconv('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'WINDOWS-1252', final_csv_str)
3. I'm using FasterCSV.generate to create the csv string. I've tried using FasterCSV.generate(:encoding => "u"). This also didn't work since the default itself is utf-8.
4. When I opened the file in LibreOffice by default it was selecting the encoding as ISO-8859-14. I tried converting UTF-8 to that format as well. It didn't workout.

I'm guessing there is some kind of header that I should prepend to the file itself, for the file to be recognised as UTF-8 encoding, Since setting the charset=utf-8 will only notify the browser.

Can anybody suggest some ideas ?

**UPDATE :**

My actual requirement was to make the files work without needing the user to do any additional steps. For this requirement the following solution works

1. Convert CSV to UTF-16
2. Insert BOM at beginning of file
3. Use tab as field separator

Someone went and tried out all combinations of the above three and found this out.
*Reference :* https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/CSV+tests+of+encoding+and+column+separator?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com

The source which led to above link is from this post :

[Microsoft Excel mangles Diacritics in .csv files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files)

For our use case just prepending BOM character sequence ("\xEF\xBB\xBF") to beginning of csv string works.

Reference :

[How to write BOM marker to a file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886705/how-to-write-bom-marker-to-a-file-in-ruby)

Other useful questions

1. [Is it possible to force Excel recognize UTF-8 CSV files automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically)
2. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372692/should-utf-8-csv-files-contain-a-bom-byte-order-mark
3. [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom/2223926#2223926)
4. [How to write BOM marker to a file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886705/how-to-write-bom-marker-to-a-file-in-ruby)

Comment: can you please share this how you solve this issue ?@Bala